# Forecasting neuralnet(): Error in is.constant(y) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, time, neural-network, forecasting

I am trying to forecast load data by using the neuralnet() function, however, when I try the forecast() function I receive the error: Error in is.constant(y) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

My data looks as follows:

```
         date  temperature   load   weekday month weekend day
1    2010-01-01         -28 256131       5    01       0   1
2    2010-01-02         -24 277749       6    01       1   2
3    2010-01-03         -53 264166       0    01       1   3
4    2010-01-04         -42 319847       1    01       0   4
5    2010-01-05         -17 321376       2    01       0   5
```

and is structured:

```
str(NLtrain)
'data.frame':   2191 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ date       : POSIXct, format: "2010-01-01" "2010-01-02" "2010-01-03" ...
 $ temperature: num  -28 -24 -53 -42 -17 -45 -43 -42 -25 -11 ...
 $ load       : num  256131 277749 264166 319847 321376 ...
 $ weekend    : num  0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ weekday    : int  5 6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 ...
 $ month      : chr  "01" "01" "01" "01" ...
 $ day        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

The code I have used :

```
 loadts <- ts(NLtrain$load, frequency=7, start = c(2010,1,1)) 

 nnvar = NLtrain$weekday+NLtrain$day+NLtrain$temperature 

 nn = neuralnet(loadts~nnvar, 
           data = NLtrain, hidden = 3, 
           linear.output =FALSE)
 forecast(nn)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you also output the structure of your data (using `str`)?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik have added the structure!

Answer (score 0):

The way you are defining the formula for your `neuralnet()` is not correct.
The "nnvar" becomes a vector the way you have explained it. It is the sum of columns. Use the following way

```
nnvar<-as.formula(loadts~weekday+day+temperature)

nn=neuralnet(nnvar,data=NLtrain,hidden=3,linear.output=F)
```

Also, as your values in loadts are not in interval from (0,1), I think you should not use linear.output=F, as in this case logistic function becomes the activation function and your values are limited to 0-1

Comment: I am still getting the same error.. I tried the following: `nnvar <- as.formula(loadts~weekday+day+temperature) 
nn = neuralnet(nnvar, data = NLtrain, hidden = 3 )
forecast(nn)`

Comment: You should checkout the forecast() function using ?forecast. It is used for time series modelling. It does not recognise NN models. Also the arguments passed to the function are also wrong.